# Rails tire(elasticsearch) search through has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have 2 associations

```
belongs_to :author
has_many :favorites
```

I'm wondering why this example works:

```
tire.search(load: {include: [:author, :comments]}, page: params[:page], per_page: 8) do
  query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
  filter :term, author_id: ['111']
  sort { by :created_at, 'desc' }
end
```

And this one doesnt:

```
tire.search(load: {include: [:author, :comments]}, page: params[:page], per_page: 8) do
  query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
  filter :term, favorite_ids: ['567']
  sort { by :created_at, 'desc' }
end
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are stored in the child table, Rails does the joining of the two tables for you.

So in this model, there is an attribute `author_id` because this model **belongs to** an author. The foreign keys for the favorites relationship are stored in the favorites table. While you can do `Model.first.favorites` and get the corresponding `favorites`, it is because of a value stored in the latter table.

`Model.first.author_id` exists. `Model.first.favorite_ids` does not.

If you want to run a search on `favorites_ids`, you're going to need to explicitly define that in the `to_indexed_json` method.

Also, [tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire) has been retired. You should look into migrating to [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails), or my preferred gem, [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick)!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't switch to another gem. As you said, I've added this code `def to_indexed_json
    to_json( include: :favorites )
  end` but it doesn't give me any change. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm uncertain if you can just use `include` and declare the children. Can you try adding them like this? `def to_indexed_json  favorite_ids: favorites.collect{|f| f.id} end`?